# jquery set a key value

Tags: jquery, local-storage

Well I've got the next code in a javascript file -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    localStorage.clear();
    var listOfNames = [{
        name: "Dan",
        selected = "false"
    }, {
        name: "Ben",
        selected: "false"
    }];
    localStorage.setItem("namesList", JSON.stringify(listOfNames));
    //}
});
```

And what i would like to happen is simple - i want by a click of a button (one says dan and the other one ben) the selected key will turn into "true" and will be save. 
so than i would be able to present the selected name in another html page.

I tried to do as fallows - in the script of the html page -

```
var dataNames = localStorage.getItem("namesList");
var names = JSON.parse(dataNames);

function select(i) {
    names[i].selected = "true";
}
```

But it turns out that the value changed but from some reason , when i try to a access to the java script file (with the names) from another html page it says the the selected key is still false.

so what i am trying to ask is how could i save the value for a key, and make it "remember" the change so it can be noticed when reading the data from another html page.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help

Comment: You need to do `localStorage.setItem("namesList", JSON.stringify(names));` after you change `selected` to `true`.

Comment: Thank you very much - that's sure works fine now - thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't saving the updated object to localStorage.

Change:

```
function select(i) {
    names[i].selected = "true";
}
```

to:

```
function select(i) {
    names[i].selected = "true";
    localStorage.setItem("namesList", JSON.stringify(names));
}
```